# Nginx is not running in docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

## My Docker File:-

```
FROM basecentos6
MAINTAINER user@gmail.com
RUN yum -y update && yum install -y epel-release && yum install -y nginx && yum install -y git && yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

## Docker container

```
sudo docker run -p80:80 -it withnginx6 bash
```

After creating container i am checking status of nginx using below command

```
service nginx status
```

it says nginx is stopped.

How to make nginx running inside container using docker file using CMD option

Comment: Why not use ```nginx``` official image container? well, try to see the logs from ```docker logs id_container``` 
https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Comment: you should check nginx process is running or not ? using command: `ps aux | grep nginx` in container ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have run the container in order the CMD command starts, if not, you are overwriting the init process with the bash command. Once it starts you can open a connection into the container and check:

```
$ docker run withnginx6
$ docker exec -it ae0b5b04a3a1 bash # assuming id of the container that's running
  [root@ae0b5b04a3a1 /]# service nginx status
  nginx (pid  1) is running...
```

Comment: Yes !!. It worked. . Interactive mode blocking the CMD daemon .

Answer (score 0):

Writing a Dockerfile based on centos and installing nginx and so on, is not a good practice for using dockerized nginx. Nginx has own official docker image. You can read more on [this page](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

I highly recommend use this method:

1. write your nginx config file.
2. run nginx container using
   `docker run -v /path/to/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.conf -p 80:80 nginx`